# как получить getFragmentManager() в классе наследуемом от SurfaceView

Tags: android, dialogfragment, android-canvas, glsurfaceview

В этом классе создается поток в котором реализован игровой цикл. И в определенный момент мне требуется вызвать `DialogFragment`

```
Dialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"GameOver");
```

Но `getFragmentManager()` я могу получить только в классе наследуемом от `AppCompatActivity`   .  Такой же вопрос уже был в англоязычном stackoverflow , но я так и понял ответ. Вот он https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268422/show-dialog-in-game-with-canvas

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity implements GetDialog {

    private static final String TAG= Menu.class.getSimpleName();

    MainGamePanel mainGamePanel;
    static float width,height;
    static  boolean pauseGame = true;
    DialogFragment GameOverFragment;



    @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Display currentDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        width = currentDisplay.getWidth();
        height = currentDisplay.getHeight();
        // запрос на отключение строки заголовка
        /*requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // перевод приложения в полноэкранный режим
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);*/
        mainGamePanel = new MainGamePanel(this);

        mainGamePanel.setInterface(this);

        setContentView(mainGamePanel);
        Log.d(TAG,"onCreate...");

    }


    public void showDialog(){
        GameOverFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dlg1");
    }

}
```

.

```
public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SoundPool sounds;
    private int sExplosion;
    private int mStreamID;
    private AssetManager mAssetManager;
    private static final String TAG = MainThread.class.getSimpleName();
    private MainThread thread;
    private Chronometer Treadchronometer;
    private mainCharacter Character, Character1, Character2, Character3, Character4;
    private Time time;
    Menu menu = new Menu();
    public static long mLastTick;
    private float mSecondsElapsedTotal;
    float pSecondsElapsed;
    Bitmap touchpad;
    boolean Created, Destroy;
    Bitmap[] myArray = new Bitmap[11];
    View mSurfaceView,mSurfaceHolder;
    GetDialog mGetDialog;


    public MainGamePanel(Context context) {
        super(context);

      getHolder().addCallback(this);

        mGetDialog.showDialog();

        // делаем GamePanel focusable, чтобы она могла обрабатывать сообщения
        setFocusable(true);
    }



    public void setInterface(GetDialog name){
        mGetDialog = name;
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        Log.d(TAG,"surfaceChanged");
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        mLastTick = System.nanoTime();// время от которого отсчитывается   время на Update игровой ситуации

            Log.d(TAG,"surfaceCreated");
            thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
            thread.setRunning(true);
            thread.start();
            Treadchronometer = new Chronometer();
            Treadchronometer.setRunning(true);
            Treadchronometer.start();
    }




    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            destroy();
    }



    public  synchronized void destroy(){

        if(thread == null){
            return;
        }                    // Добавить проверку на Null потока Treadchronometer
        boolean retry = true;
        thread.setRunning(false);
        Treadchronometer.setRunning(false);
        while (retry){
            try{
                Treadchronometer.join();
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ignored){
            }
        }
        thread = null;
        Treadchronometer = null;
        Log.d(TAG,"surfaceDestroyed");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создайте интерфейс с методом `void showDialog()`
2. Имплементируйте его в актвити.
3. Создайте поле с типом интерфеса в нужном классе. Создайте сеттер к нему.
4. В актвити, при создании экземпляра вашего класса вызовите метод-сеттер и передайте в него актвити.
5. В классе в нужный момент вызовите метод из п.1 у переменной и п.3 - так вызовется метод из п.1 реализованный в актвити. А там у вас есть доступ к `FragmentManager`

Comment: Так..Пункт один сделал, создал в нем метод. Пункт 2 сделал , в активити естественно создал пустой метод  public void showDialog(){}. Третий пункт. Поле с типом интерфейса ? как оно объявляется, создается?  Пункт 4 . т.е. присвоить этому созданному в 3 пункте активити. Как?   ( У меня очень слабая база в ООП  и Java , но игру добить хочу,прежде чем начать читать книги)

Comment: Вам надо на уровне класса объявить переменную так: `ИмяИнтерфейса mInterface;`. Создать сеттер к нему `public void setInterface(ИмяИнтерфейса name){mInterface = name; }` Потом где-то - `переменнаяВашегоКласса.setInterface(this);`

Comment: Вы что-то не так делаете. Что именно - хз, вы код не показали. И про интерфейчы вы что-то непонятное сказали

Comment: Нет , нет, там была ошибка потому что я не объявил dialogfragment . Сейчас проблема в том , что при вызове из этого класса метод из интерфейса реализованный в активити выходит ошибка.. Ссылка на нулевой объект. У меня активити становится onStop() после того как вызовется экземпляр моего класса. И когда я из этого класса хочу обратиться к методу интерфейса выходит ошибка

Comment: Я приложил код, не обращайте внимание на кучу объявленных переменных которых нет в коде. Ну как я понимаю, сейчас проблема в том ,активити уходит в Stop и воспользоваться этим интерфейсом не получается

Comment: У вас что-то, кажется, неправльно с архитекрутой и с пониманием жизненного цикла актвити. Но я слабо представляю как вы сможеже кратко в рамках вопроса описать структуру того что вы сделали и как оно работает

Comment: Ну вот в приложенном коде класс Menu создается экземпляр класса MainGamePanel .и setContentView(mainGamePanel).    Класс MainGamePanel не имеет своего loyaut , он заменяет собой активити. вот прочтя это вы поймете что у меня за архитектура https://toster.ru/q/230362

Comment: Всё ещё не понятно почему у вас останавливается актвити и что конкретно происходит в show методе диалога

Comment: Благодарю Вас. 12 часов за компьютеров дали о себе знать. Я тупо запутался в своих логах , активити не останавливается . В лог выводилось: D/ContentValues: Stopping menu    я пониимаю это просто значение переменной?  а после выхода из активити уже D/Menu: Stopping menu .     И еще я объявил DialogFragment , но не инициализировал в методе onCreate(). Теперь всё работает , спасибо.

Comment: Юрий, мне снова нужна ваша помощь, мне пришлось брать SurfaceView из xml и поэтому конструктор класса стал такой          public MainGamePanel(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);             И четвертый пункт в вашем ответе больше не работает,   переменнаяВашегоКласса.setInterface(this);         Пишет, что MainGamePanel(Context , AttributeSet ) in MainGamePanel cannot be applied to (Menu)    Menu -  это класс активити

Comment: @Turalllb, вы пытаетесь в конструктор активти передать. А я писал о создании отдельного метода-сеттера. Вот его создайте и его вызывайте и в него актвити передавайте

Comment: Так и сделано. mainGamePanel = new MainGamePanel(this); mainGamePanel.setInterface(this);     Всё работало , до тех пор пока я конструктор не изменил . Теперь я не могу инициализировать экземпляр класса, как я понимаю

Comment: Если он вас в теперь в разметке, то инициализировать надо находя в разметке так: `findViewById(R.id.someId)`

Comment: Никак не пойму.. я объявляю MainGamePanel mainGamePanel; инициализирую  mainGamePanel =  (MainGamePanel) findViewById(R.id.surface);    и   mainGamePanel.setInterface(this);   Пишет method 'void example.igeniy.MainGamePanel.interface(example.igeniy.GetDialog)' on a null object reference    P.S. никак не могу код форматировать , ctrl+k не работает

Comment: Получаю ровно такую же ошибку как в этом моем коде http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612271        я там так же инициализирую mSurfaceView  и получаю ссылку на нулевой объект..я как то не правильно инициализирую что ли..

Comment: мой комментарий выше не к месту.   в общем если убрать mainGamePanel.setInterface(this); то все работает, естественно до тех пор пока не должен появиться фрагмент. А если есть mainGamePanel.setInterface(this)  то получаю ошибку. сам mainGamePanel проинициализирован   mainGamePanel = (MainGamePanel) findViewById(R.id.surface);

Comment: @Turalllb, попробуйте отдельный вопрос задать. У вас либо опечатка где-то, в ID например, или вы столкнулись с отличным от обычных View поведением SurfaceView

Comment: ну если бы id не был верным , то ничего бы не работало, а без строки  mainGamePanel.setInterface(this) всё работает, пока мне фрагмент не понадобится. Ок сейчас сформулирую новый вопрос

Comment: @Turalllb, если код у вас не очень изменился, то у вас null, т.к. вы пытаетесь искать View **ДО** рагрузки разметки актвити методом `setContentView`

Comment: Вы очень вовремя, а то я уже было начал новый вопрос писать) Буду впредь обращать внимание на это. И правда загрузка разметки ушла в самый низ пока я модифицировал остальной код. Тяжело кодить после суток на дежурстве, но хочется творить) Спасибо!